# Laravel hasMany relationship not accessing the relationship

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-4

**Controller function** (That should return 2 results, with their location and message count):

```
public function getIndex()
    {   
        $alerts = User::with('alerts.location')
                  ->where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        $this->layout->content = View::make('agents.index', 
                  array('alerts' => $alerts));
    }
```

User model:

```
public function alerts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Alert');
    }
```

Alert model:

```
public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Location');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Message');
    }
```

**View:**

```
 @foreach($alerts as $alert)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $alert->location->address_1}}</td>
    <td>{{ $alert->location->address_2}}</td>
    <td>{{ $alert->location->address_3}}</td>
    <td>{{ $alert->location->postcode}}</td>
    <td>{{ $alert->messages->count()}}</td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Any echo which tries to access `location` or `messages` fails -

> ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object

I changed the query from a ->first() method, to a ->get() method, which is where the problem started. Each alert definitely has multiple messages and 1 location associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like $alerts is an array of User and you're using it as an array of Alert.
Try this:

```
$alerts = User::with('alerts.location')
          ->where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first()->alerts;
```

The problem with get() is that it returns an array, even if there are 0 or 1 results and it seems like you're only expecting a single result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$alerts = User::with('alerts.location')->where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Above line returns Eloquent Collection of one User model with eager loaded nested relation, but not alerts like you would like and you don't eager load messages here, so you will face n+1 issue in the foreach loop.
Also you already loaded user in Auth::user() so no need to query users table again.

Instead use this:

```
$alerts = Auth::user()->alerts // this loads all alerts as a Collection
           ->load('location')  // here we eager load related Location for every Alert
           ->load('messages'); // and here we eager load related messages for all Alerts


// now $allerts is a Collection of Alert models and related Local models
// so this will work (Still add some check for ->location as it might be null
// if there is no related location for an alert):
  @foreach($alerts as $alert)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $alert->location->address_1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ $alert->location->address_2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ $alert->location->address_3 }}</td>
    <td>{{ $alert->location->postcode }}</td>
    <td>{{ $alert->messages->count() }}</td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
```